# I want to adapt a MySQL query to postgreSQL

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, yii2

I am trying to make a browser for videos in my page using Yii2 and PostgreSQL and the reference code i have is for MySQL. I understand that the function "andWhere" generate the SQL query given the MySQL code.

The query I am trying to convert in the php file is:

```
   SELECT title
   FROM video
   WHERE to_tsvector(title || ' ' || tags) @@ to_tsquery(:keyword)
```

And the reference code for MySQL is:

```
return $this->andWhere("MATCH(title, description, tags)
AGAINST (:keyword)", ['keyword' => $keyword]);
```

Please help, I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### ActiveRecord helps you write database agnostic queries.

ActiveRecord lets you write queries without having to worry about the supporting database. You can even change the database engine that your application uses without having to modify your queries.

This code should work for your use case

```php
$this->where(['or', 
    ['like', 'title', $keyword],
    ['like', 'description', $keyword],
    ['like', 'tags', $keyword]
]);
```

I am not sure why you are using `andWhere()` in your question, if you already have a `where()` higher up in your method, then use `andWhere`.

The Yii2 documentation has a [nice page](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-queryinterface#where()-detail) on how to specify query conditions.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly, now i will read the Yii2 documentation.